# eclipse jetty plugin Cross origin support Class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty, cors

I am trying to use Cross Origin Filter support for my web application. I am using eclipse jetty plugin to debug it from eclipse. When I run the class through console, using mvn jetty:run, I always get correct response. But when I run it using my jetty eclipse plugin, I get Class not found exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
```

I have the following dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
<version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
</dependency>
```

When I check the classpath configurations of my jetty project in eclipse, I see this dependency present as maven dependencies. Still I am not sure why the jetty plugin is not able to find  org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter as a part of classpath. Kindly help me with this.

edit:

Looks like it is not only for the CORS. Even other classes present in web.xml throws error for class not found. I checked in the jetty classpath of that debug configuration and able to find these jars in there. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 6):

That can't be part of your webapps `WEB-INF/lib` directory (not supported that way, as it cant access the internal server components it needs).

Enable the `servlets` module in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` instead

```
--module=servlets
```

Comment: Hi Joakim, Thanks for your reply. Since I am using eclipse jetty plugin, I am not sure where to find the start.ini I tried looking for that and not seeing it. Instead I found, the eclipse jetty plugin config xml file. I went about manually adding the jars as dependencies for the jetty plugin in the eclipse debug configurations for that. I can see those jars added as extra classpath entry in that eclipse jetty config xml. Now that issue is resolved. But the pain is looks like I might need to add all the dependent jars of my project one by one to resolve all the errors.

Comment: Considering that the Eclipse Jetty project doesn't create / release / or promote an "Eclipse Jetty Plugin", I would guess that you would need to talk to the 3rd party that develops that plugin you are using.

Comment: Thanks Joakim for your response. I fixed the issue by enabling Include other dependencies without scope in the plugin configs. That resulted in adding all the dependencies while running the jetty plugin.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Is http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html not part of the Eclipse Jetty project? Thanks for your input

Comment: @geoand Your statement "Eclipse Jetty Plugin" refers to a Jetty plugin for the Eclipse IDE (this also includes WTP support).  We do not maintain a Eclipse IDE based plugin.  The jetty-maven-plugin is not an "Eclipse Jetty Plugin", that's for maven itself, and yes, that we do maintain and support.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure that the following is the best solution possible, however it does work:

First of all I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-maven.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Notice that I used the `test` score here in order to avoid leaking the dependencies used solely for the Maven Jetty plugin into the production artifact.
In order for the Maven Jetty plugin to be able to use this dependency (since it doesn't by default use the test scope), you need to enable

`<useTestScope>true</useTestScope>` in the `configuration` part of the plugin